# Check Type Javascript

Tags: javascript

Question:
I confuse the operator explain description below: Is that correct?

```
var length = "50";

if (length === 50) {...} // It allows for a block of code to fire if the length equals 50 regardless of the data type.
```

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does it matter which equals operator (== vs ===) I use in JavaScript comparisons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons)

Comment: That's what `==` will do - type coercion. `===` enforces that the two operands are the same type (and value, obviously)

Comment: Nope, that's backwards. `==` allows type coercion (operands can be different but "compatible" types), while `===` is a strict comparison that doesn't do type coercion (operands have to be the exact same type). [Comparison operator docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2FComparison_Operators).

Comment: Please do some basic research. This is in the first chapter of any manual.

Comment: Just read the documentation and you will know whether it is correct or not. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Comment: Not that it will be easy to read/follow at first, but here's the "official" specs on how the two operators should work internally: http://es5.github.io/#x11.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a == b` means check if a is equal to b, and don't worry about what types they are

`a === b` means check if a is exactly, type and all, equal to b

Comment: My question is the explanation on the code is correct or not correct!

Answer (score 1):

`==` checks if the 2 values are the same.
`===` checks if the 2 values are the same and are of the same type.